# Which song plays at 18:00 in episode 4 season 3 of Boku No Hero Academia?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Which song plays when Midoriya decides to fight the muscular man with everything he has got, and says "Stay Back, Kota. And then, when it hits, you run as fast as you can back to camp."

At the time of this scene the song is halfway through though.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think [this is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Soc5SkrkLn4) what you are looking for.

Comment: The original OST was not released yet, that is some fan made!

Comment: I think title of the video was enough to understand that.

Comment: So basically the OP asks for the song that plays at 18:00 and you give him a fan made?

Answer (score 0):

Who ever was looking for this song, it has been released :D

It's called. One For all Vs All For One

here is the original track that someone uploaded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gDXwLjHyfo

and there is the info of the tracks on Season 3:

https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia_2018_Original_Soundtrack

I have been looking for that song all along trust me, im so happy that I found it now >D